# setting up USB serial port numbers

Tags: linux, unix, serial-port, usbserial

One of the scripts that i have been given to work with uses port numbers to communicate to the serial port like

```
 4001
 4002
```

Using a USB Serial hub which is connected to one machine and running the script from another machine but the actual ports are like,

```
/dev/ttyUSB0 
/dev/ttyUSB1
```

How do i map `/dev/ttyUSB0` with 4001 so that when i call the script and pass 192.168.X.X:4001, it should be able to communicate to the serial port ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to do the mapping, you are going to need some sort of daemon that can do the job.  I have used ser2net to good effect to accomplish this.  The ser2net daemon uses a configuration file to set up the port to service wrapper(s).